# How to fetch value of particular column with where condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frames below and need to fetch the value of D only where A=12.0.

```
          A     B   C     D
Row_1  12.0   7.0  20  14.0
Row_2   4.0   2.0  16   3.0
Row_3   5.0  54.0  11   NaN
Row_4   NaN   3.0   3   2.0
Row_5   1.0   NaN   8   6.0
```

I have tried this, but getting error:

```
result = df.loc['A'==12.0, 'D']
print(result)
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: `result = df.loc[df['A']==12.0, 'D']` ?

Comment: or df.loc[np.where(df['A'] == 12.0, True, False)]['D']

Comment: @Rakesh I am getting this: 

Row_1    14.0
Name: D, dtype: float64  But I only want 14.0 as a result

Comment: `.loc` always give you a series. So do: `df.loc[df.A.eq(12),'D'][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because you are looking for 'A'==12.0, so you are basically looking for False, that is not in the dataframe. You need

```
result = df.loc[df['A']==12.0, 'D'][0]
```

The final [0] is to take the first element of the series returned by df.loc

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[12.0, 4.0, 5.0, np.nan, 1.0], 'B':[7.0, 2.0, 54.0, 3.0, np.nan], 'C':[20, 16, 11, 3, 8], 'D':[14.0, 3.0, np.nan, 2.0, 6.0]})
print(df.loc[df.A==12.0]['D'])
print(df.loc[df.A==12.0]['D'][0])
```

output:

```
0    14.0
Name: D, dtype: float64

14.0
```